# Determining the probability of unique values chosen from a larger set?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to solve what I think is a more generalized version of the "birthday paradox".  I run into problems like this all the time and I can never quite figure out how to tackle them.

Suppose I have a set of $M$ possibilities all with an equal probability of being chosen: $\operatorname{P}(M_n) = 1/M$.  Now suppose I pick from the set of possibilities $N$ times.  I'd like to know the probability of there being $C$ unique values chosen.  I'd also like to know the probability of the tails.

This strikes me as related to the Birthday paradox.

To make the problem more concrete, I'm currently trying to figure out how unexpected an event is.  I have $156$ salts chosen where each salt is a $12\mathrm{-bit}$ number.  Only $147$ salts were unique.  That is, $9$ of them are duplicates.  So $M = 2^{12} = 4096$ and $N = 156$.  I'd like to calculate the probability that there were exactly $147$ unique salts chosen.  I'd also like to be able to compute the probably of *at least* $147$ and *at most* $147$.

Is there a probability distribution for this?  Maybe something like the Poisson distribution?

Comment: I should mention that for small version of the problem like my concrete example I'm able to write code to simulate it.  That's a pretty lame hack though when I think there must be an easy way to calculate the exact probability rather than run thousands of trials to approximate it.

Comment: There may not be a computationally useful expression for the probabilities. The *mean* should not be difficult. Probably variance is not too hard either. Then the Chebyshev Inequality gives some weak information about tails.

Comment: I thought all 4096 would be unique.  I really do not understand why in your concrete example, you will choose 147 salts that are unique? - Andre correct me if I am wrong.  I had a similar question solved.  In that he wanted 15 sets of objects of which there were many of them them the same, if you had 4 green balls you want to place one gree ball in a slot, then the number of ways he wanted was 4 and it contained duplicates, makes sense, but not in your concrete example, Correct me if I am wrong Andre

Comment: @satishramanathan There are 4096 salt possibilities.  I chose 156 of them at random and got 147 unique ones.  That is, 9 times I chose a salt I'd already chosen.  I'd like to know what the probability of getting 147 was.  Was it very unexpected?  For example if I'd gotten 10 unique ones that would be exceptionally unexpected and would have a probability near 0.  At the same time, if I'd gotten 156 unique I could calculate that probability with the birthday problem.

Comment: Now this makes sense, I am sorry for the misunderstanding.  Understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the Bernoulli random variable $X_i$ to be one if the number $i$ is chosen and zero otherwise. Then the number of distinct numbers chosen is $X:= X_1+\cdots+X_N$. Each $X_i$ is zero with probability $\left(1-\frac 1 M\right)^N$. Hence, $E[X_i]= 1-\left(1-\frac 1 M\right)^N$, and by the linearity of expectation,
$$E[X] = N\cdot\left(1-\left(1-\frac 1 M\right)^N\right)$$
which yields
$$ N\cdot\left(1-\exp(-N/M)\right)\le E[X]\le N\cdot\left(1-4^{-N/M}\right)$$

Although $X_i$'s are not independent, we can still get tail estimates by applying [Chernoff bounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) on $X$ since they seem to be "[negatively dependent](http://www.brics.dk/RS/96/25/BRICS-RS-96-25.pdf)" (roughly, knowing that a subset of $X_i$'s are high does not increase the chance of other disjoint subsets being high).

In fact, the problem you are considering is the number of non-empty bins in a balls into bins experience with $N$ balls and $M$ bins. This model is well explored - as far as I know, there are at least tail bounds on [the number of empty bins](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/courses/787-F09/scribe-notes/lec7.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

To end up with $C$ unique values, you'd have to select one of $\binom{M}{C}$ possibilities, and spread the remaining $N-C$ options among the $C$ selected.

That leads to $\binom{M}{C}\binom{C}{N-C}$ ways out of $N^M$.

I am not sure that this answers your question.